# useEffect missing dependency warning with ref in custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, eslint, ref

In React Typescript with the exhaustive-deps rule enabled, when I define a ref and use that inside of an effect, the linter is fine with it:

```
const stringRef: RefObject<string> = useRef("Hello World!");
  
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(stringRef.current);
}, []) // no warning, the linter detects that I'm using a ref
```

However, when I put the effect inside of a custom hook, the linter complains that I should include the ref inside of the dependency array:

```
const stringRef: RefObject<string> = useRef("Hello World!");
  
useCustomHook(stringRef);

// in another-file.ts
const useCustomHook = (ref: RefObject<string>) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(ref.current);
  }, []) // ESLint: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'ref'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)
}
```

Semantically, nothing changed, however, the linter doesn't recognize that ref is a RefObject (even though I typed it as such).

The big question now is: **How can I make the linter know that the given dependency doesn't need to be included in the dependency array without suppressing the warning?**

For me, it's a major drawback that this is not possible, because I can't convert my effects into custom hooks without the linter complaining.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am curious as to why it says so. If your ref.current here was a non-primitive instead of a primitive like string, do you see the same behaviour ?

Comment: @LakshyaThakur the warning is always shown, also when the ref is an object or a dom ref (HTMLElement). But -as alredy stated- only on custom effects (in extra files), when the ref is not in the surrounding scope of the effect (but passed as an argument). If the ref is in the surrounding scope of the effect, a warning is never shown

Comment: isn't the `ref` object returned by `useRef` stable? you can use it safely as a dependency in your custom effect

Comment: I agree with @thedude, if you are confident that ref is stable (and it should be, it's a ref) then just put it in the dependency array. It wont trigger the useEffect unless the ref itself is redeclared, which should only happen on the components initial render. Don't be afraid to put stuff in the dependency array if you are confident in their stability.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I thought there would be a more smart way to satisfy the linter. By adding the ref as a dependency even though it's a ref I kind of "pollute" the dependency array and distract attention from the dependencies that are mandatory to be included. But hey, guess I'll have to accept that drawback!

Answer (score 2):

You can't configure it out of the box.

The linter (`eslint`) is a static code analyzer. It only analyzes text patterns without compiling the code, i.e it doesn't know the "meaning" of what is written.

For example, it sees the "`use***()`" pattern and believes its a custom hook, then it verifies it with Rules of Hooks patterns like not having such text in `if` statement.

See for yourself:

> Reminder: Custom hook is a function with 'use' prefix **and** a function which uses hooks.

```
// NOT A CUSTOM HOOK, just a function with 'use' prefix
const useConsole = () => console.log("hello");

// Normal function
const logHello = () => console.log("hello2");

const Component = () => {
  if (true) {
    // Warning - React hook is called conditionally
    useConsole();

    // OK
    logHello();
  }
  return <>Example</>;
};
```

[image: Edit Eslint Example]

But, you always can [propose a custom rule](https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/contributing/new-rules) to identify `RefObject<string>` and `useEffect` in same scope.

From the Typescript compiler side, it doesn't violate anything as the use case matches the `useEffect` type.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the **useEffect1** and **useEffect2** is that `stringRef` is a constant so by definition **const** doesn't change but in example 2 `ref` is a **variable** that can be changed, so you have to add the argument as a dependency.

Answer (score -4):

You can disable the rule using // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps otherwise you can move the ref inside of useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
   // other code
   ...

   // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [])
```

Comment: As already said, I don't want do suppress the warning, because by that I might miss future dependencies that need to be added